# JSON request not working

Tags: javascript, php, json

So I am trying to get data from http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singleorderdata&marketid=132 however it doesn't seem to be responding.

The code is simple:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singleorderdata&marketid=132', function(data){
alert(data.return.DOGE.sellorders[0].price);
});
</script>
```

However when I try the exact same code with http://jsbin.com/pudoki/1.json, which has the exact same content as the previous URL it works.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('http://jsbin.com/pudoki/1.json', function(data){
alert(data.return.DOGE.sellorders[0].price);
});
</script>
```

Does anyone have any idea why? Is it a permissions issue? The page with the first code snippet on (non-working one) just appears white with no alert/pop-up.

Thanks!

Comment: CORS is not enabled on the first URL. The message I get is: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: @Octopus I see, I have a variable that relates to CURL and that gets the same info: $currentsellprice = $currentdmarket['return']['sellorders']['0']['sellprice']; do you know how I could intergrate that variable with the javascript code above?

Comment: You could have curl grab it via your server and then deliver it to your js. That way your js doesn't see that you are crossing domains (it would in fact be coming from your own).

Comment: @Octopus Yeh I just don't know how to reference the php variable $currentsellprice in the javascript. Like var final = <?php echo $currentsellprice; ?> ? how would I do that.

Comment: @Octopus solved it. Thanks for the help. var final = <?php echo $currentsellprice; ?> * 1.005 was the solution.